# cronopete "enable-folder-backend" does not show up in dconf Editor in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, backup, storage, dconf

I use a combination of Timeshift and Cronopete for backups. My desktop has some internal HDDs that are used for doing backups. The system is on a separate NVMe.

I was able to get this working for Timeshift, but Cronopete expects there to be USB storage as the backup media. If you try to "Store backups in a folder", which seems is how'd I'd pick these internal HDDs as the backup destination, you get this message:

[image]

Reading the following link, it sounds like I need to install dconf Editor and toggle `enable-folder-backend` to on:

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/cronopete-time-machine-like-backup-tool/

However, when I navigate there, `enable-folder-backend` does not appear as an option:
[image]

I'm using the "Ubuntu focal 64-bit" installer located here:

https://rastersoft.com/programas/cronopete.html

Suggestions for how to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i had installed Dconf Editor as a flatpak, uninstalled and used the deb version and this fixed it. hopes this helps someone